# Are there better functions than redirect() and render()? [Node Application]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently creating a Node betting application and I when I post to the DB, I need to redirect back to the index page. Currently my workaround is to render the index.hbs page however this will be rendered at mywebsite.com/bet and that's a problem. I've looked at using res.redirect() but the problem there is I can't carry  in my session information (user: req.user) or my collection items I wish to render on the page (items: doc)

```
app.post('/bet', function(req, res){
   // All betting functionality above and when completed do the following

        Collection.find(query).limit(10)
            .then(function(doc){
                res.render('index', {title: 'MyWebsite | Home', items: doc, user: req.user, 
                                     message: req.flash('bet-update')});
        });
 });
```

Are there any smarter ways to get the index page to render with the relevant data? Is it possible to send a GET request from within a POST function after it's finished? My app.get('/') function does exactly what I need it to do but it's a mess when I have to copy and paste the same code into every POST request function in Node.

Comment: uhm..... ajax....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `POST` and redirect to a page that shows the list you are interested in.

Imagine a trivial example. You could have a `GET /bets` page. This page will retrieve the user session and will show the list of the user bets.
Then the user decides to place a new bet. You will call `POST /bets` to execute all the betting logic. At this point you are ready to redirect the user back to your `GET /bets` that will show the updated list.

The whole point is to extract the viewing logic to a dedicated page and redirected to that when finished with the `POST`. It is applicable to your case?

Comment: That's a good suggestion but perhaps I didn't give enough information. there doesn't exist a /bets page. Users can view the betting markets at the home page just like any bookie website and then when they add to the betslip and click Place Bet it POSTs to /bets and then gets handled there, then I need to redirect back to the home page once again but with the extra data from the session/mongo.

Comment: Couldn't you save that data in session and always check the session in the homepage if there's anything relevant to show?